# pscp - special characters in username and password

Tags: pscp

I'm trying to run the following pscp.exe line and I keep getting failure and the list of options from pscp.exe: (I've swapped in content for host, username and password but left some special characters that are actually supposed to be in the fields):

```
pscp -v -l 123456789@sftp.server.org -pw abcDEF@12(345%XWZ MYFILE.zip server.host.org:foldername
```

How do I cope with the < @ . ( and % > in the username and password? I've tried \ escape and I get the same issue all the way through.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: I've experimented with swapping in clean text and it appears that it's the % in the password causing the problem. But how do I escape it?

Comment: Probably not escaping correctly. What environment is this?

Comment: It was pscp.exe on windows.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that to escape a `%` in this particular instance, you use `%%`.